# Angular Typescript type ERROR when using Array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, reduce

let say I have two arrays of typed object (same type), and I want to merge them, checking if an object already exists, then sum the old and new amount and return a new array with updated values

**model**:

```
class Ingredient {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number){ }
}
```

**arrays**:

```
  private ingredients: Ingredient[] = [
    new Ingredient('farina', 500),
    new Ingredient('burro', 80),
    new Ingredient('uccellini', 5)
  ];

  private newIngredients: Ingredient[] = [
    new Ingredient('uova', 5),
    new Ingredient('pancetta', 80),
    new Ingredient('uccellini', 8)
  ];
```

when I try to create a **method** to check and merge arrays, I have an ERROR logged before to start writing my code!:

```
addIngredients(newIngredients: Ingredient[]) {

  this.ingredients
    .concat(this.newIngredients)
    .reduce((result, curr) => {

    });
}
```

This is the **error**:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(result: Ingredient, curr: Ingredient) => 
void' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'(previousValue: Ingredient, currentValue: Ingredient, currentIndex: number, array: Ingredient[]) ...'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Ingredient'.
```

I cannot move on, please help me!

Comment: You should return an `Ingredient` inside the function passed to `reduce`. Same type as `result`. Also ask yourself why you are reducing the array there? It seems highly unlikely that a method with the intention of adding something to an array would also reduce it to a single element.

Comment: try to replace `private ingredients: Ingredient[]` with `private ingredients: any`

Comment: reduce returns "void" when it has no inner code block hence the error, i would suggest also setting a default value for the accumulator of the reduce function which is the second argument.

I.E   array#reduce((a,c) => a+c, 0) where 0 is the default value for accumulator

Comment: @BalázsÉdes thanks, the error disappeared when `return result` is provided. Do you think I'm in a wrong way to do the job? I want an array with the matching elements are _reduced_ by the amount

Comment: @ShanonJackson how can I use a default value in my case?

Comment: @ufollettu Read the docs and examples on [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), I think you expect it to do something else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `.reduce` method, return `result` and the error will disappear.